# Why does Kullervo have this name?

Tags: names, companions-quartet

In the *Companions Quartet* by Julia Golding, the primary antagonist is Kullervo, an insubstantial, shapeshifting force of evil, bent on destroying humanity for the good of magical and non-magical non-human species: a supernatural eco-terrorist of sorts.

He shares a name with the [abused, incestuous, hapless character](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kullervo) from the *Kalevala*. However, the Kullervo from the *Companions Quartet* is (apparently) an extradimensional, formless entity that was never human, whereas the character from the *Kalevala* was human, and would be long deceased by the time of the *Companions Quartet* (having committed suicide). Nonetheless, it seems that there must be a connection.

Why does Kullervo have that particular name?

- Is he somehow the Kullervo from the *Kalevala*?
- Did humans name him after the Kullervo from the *Kalevala*?

Or is there some other explanation altogether?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Who better to quote than Julia Golding herself.

In short, it was from the *Kalevala* but "*set loose to take new form*".

For her characters she borrowed creatures from all mythologies and has tried to re-envision them into her universe. Golding's *Kullervo* was originally a creature who could speak on behalf of all mythical creatures, this lead her to *Kullervo* from the *Kalevala*. Another reason she chose *Kullervo* was what it's name suggested.

[image: Email from Julia Golding]

> My series has borrowed mythical creatures from all over the world and reimagined them in my universe. When looking for a powerful creature who could speak on the behalf of mythical creatures, I decided I needed someone who got a bad deal in traditional story telling and Kullervo fitted the role (not an ideal upbringing and being labelled 'evil' so early on). The name also suggests 'Kill' which is a good sound. So in response to your questioner, it was from the Kalevala but then set loose to take new form for the purposes of the story in which he appears.
>
> Best wishes
>
> Julia